# Unable to use sip-based voip software

Tags: whonix

I've been trying to get Software like Jitsi to work on whonix, however it keeps saying either there is an issue with the login information or something wrong with the network settings. I tried using this setup on my normal setup, i.e no whonix/Yor and logs into my sip account without any issues.

Comment: This answer might be helpful for you: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/101/88

Comment: @JensKubieziel Tor's Jacob Appelbaum recommends Jitsi over Skype. [source](https://jitsi.org/Main/News) Indication for not being an UDP-only client not able to use TCP?

Comment: On the other hand, Van Gegel (torfone developer) [said](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2013-June/028708.html) Jitsi is can't be routed over Tor.

Comment: Do we have any reports of someone successfully using Jitsi/Voip over Tor? Anyway. Voip/TCP-only or not, why would the login fail? @Bobby Please post the full error message / screenshot.

Comment: @adrelanos Jake recommended Jitsi in favor of Skype and not to use via Tor.

Comment: See also: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Voip