# Debian-based: torsocks + Chromium-browser = DNS Leakage?

Tags: dns, chrome, information-leaks, torsocks

System: latest Kali ( Debian-based )

```
$ torsocks chromium-browser
00:00:00 libtorsocks(1): sendmsg: Connection is a UDP or ICMP stream, may be a DNS request or other form of leak: rejecting.
00:00:00 libtorsocks(1): sendmsg: Connection is a UDP or ICMP stream, may be a DNS request or other form of leak: rejecting.
00:00:00 libtorsocks(1): sendmsg: Connection is a UDP or ICMP stream, may be a DNS request or other form of leak: rejecting.
00:00:00 libtorsocks(1): sendmsg: Connection is a UDP or ICMP stream, may be a DNS request or other form of leak: rejecting.
...
[1:1:0100/000000:FATAL:zygote_main_linux.cc(530)] Check failed: UnixDomainSocket::SendMsg(kZygoteSocketPairFd, kZygoteBootMessage, sizeof(kZygoteBootMessage), std::vector<int>()).
```

**Connection is a UDP or ICMP stream, may be a DNS request or other form of leak: rejecting.**

And doesn't work. No window of browser appearing.... Hm....

Moreover, when I'm trying to configure transparent proxy, according to official [manual](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy#Transparentlyanonymizingtrafficforaspecificuser), chromium-browser doesn't look at /etc/resolv.conf or anything else. Anyway, iptables-redirection doesn't redirect chromium's request for DNS(UDP:53), and logically .onion domains doesn't work too.

Who know the Way to launch chromium clear from DNS leakage?

Answer (score 1):

Ohai !

You can use chromium with tor like that (look man) :
chromium --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:9050"

It should work :>

Comment: Why does it not work with torsocks?

Comment: This has an answer http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1837941&p=12112303#post12112303