# Using Torrent via Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bittorrent

utorrent doesn't work from my institute computers. Can I bypass this restriction through Tor to download torrent files? If yes, how?

Comment: I've re-marked this as a duplicate of the original Torrent question and added an answer to that question that should tell you how to set it up (though it's not μTorrent specific). Hopefully this (and all the warnings against it) are helpful.

Comment: See letter b on https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en#warning

Answer (score 2):

You will probably be able to configure the µTorrent client to communicate over Tor but **please do not do this**.

There is already a very similar question: [How can BitTorrent traffic be anonymized with Tor?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/64/114) which asks for a very similar thing but for achieving anonymity. There you can read that the BitTorrent transfer would be very slow and you will create really unnecessarily high load in the Tor network.

Instead of using Tor with multi-layered encryption and routing (onion-routing) you should use much simpler VPNs or proxies with which you will get much higher throughput without the strong negative effect on other users. Just put [`BitTorrent VPN`](https://www.google.com/search?q=BitTorrent%20VPN) into a search engine to find some guidelines which are out of scope of this site.