# By pass proxy server for utorrent

Tags: bittorrent

I have an internet connection which is provided by college and they have proxy server every time I have to enter user name and password for internet access.

The torrent is blocked. When I open torrent tracker says `Access Denied`. How can I use u torrent for downloading stuffs.

I used Tor Bundle it was working then I read here [not to use](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/64/how-can-bittorrent-traffic-be-anonymized-with-tor) Tor for torrent.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother trying to torrent through Tor. If you get it working right, it will be very slow, and you'll be interfering with other Tor users. Use a VPN service that caters to torrenting. BolehVPN would be a good choice, or AirVPN. Both accept Bitcoins.

Comment: will it work with proxy server ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Some VPN services offer TCP connections on port 443 or even 80. AirVPN also provides VPN via SSH or SSL (stunnel) and that may get through. iVPN offers obfsproxy (obfs2) but they don't like bandwidth hogs ;) I've seen other VPNs promoting proprietary obfuscation methods. Search, read and test :)