# Can I use Tor for applications like Thunderbird, Torrent etc.?

Tags: windows, network-configuration

My college provides internet access via `wifi` and uses a `proxy server`. Every time when I open my browser I have to enter user name and password for internet access.

I used Tor for anonymous surfing. I want to know can I use Tor for different application like `Mozilla Thunderbird, utorrent,` etc.

Comment: Dear, How does this question relate to Tor?

Comment: lots of services are blocked like torrent, large size file download...i used Tor and got succeeded. then i read don't use Tor with torrent...is there any way to use that ?

Comment: check out i2p for torrenting. i'm not sure entirely how their torrents work, but they boast how well they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do, but a bad idea in most cases. **Most applications leak sensitive information when using with (or possibly without) Tor.** Less importantly, how necessary is it that Google doesn't know where you logged into your email.

Tor Project has a page about [Torifying](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO) and instructions on [specific applications.](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO#Clientapplications)

For Mozilla Thunderbird it is [recommended](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/EMail/Thunderbird) to use [Torbirdy.](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/torbirdy) Installation instructions can be found [here.](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/torbirdy#SetupSteps)

For a torrenting take a look at [this question.](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/64/how-can-bittorrent-traffic-be-anonymized-with-tor)

I also recommend the use of [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) as it is a live Linux OS that routes all traffic through Tor.*

> The Amnesic Incognito Live System is a live CD/USB distribution preconfigured so that everything is safely routed through Tor and leaves no trace on the local system.

*All of the applications in it are specifically configured to route through Tor and no non-Tor traffic can escape (or at least in theory.) However, it does drop unexpected/non-tor traffic.