# How do I connect "eMule" software through the Tor Connection?

Tags: configuration

How do I connect "eMule" software through the Tor annonymous Connection?

Answer (score 1):

eMule is a P2P file-sharing application. The general recommendations are that [you shouldn't run P2P over Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/68/1730), with the main reason being that the network doesn't have enough capacity to support the volume of traffic generated by file sharing.

If your aim is to use P2P anonymously, then even if you correctly configure your application to use SOCKS (which eMule does support), you would have to ensure that the application is actually adhering to your settings - this isn't always the case with file-sharing applications, as described in [this blog post](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea) on BitTorrent.

Comment: There is iMule (eMule for I2P)

Answer (score 1):

P2P applications such as eMule communicate on a different protocol than TOR. This could essentially render your security useless. A proxy of VPN that support torrenting would better suit your needs.

Comment: Can you supply a few more details on how using P2P over Tor breaks user security?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks The idea of P2P is that everybody knows where everybody else is so that they can all connect to each other. So you broadcast information on where you can be reached.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Additionally, your P2P application can take your actual IP address and send it to the tracker(s) being used. Rendering TOR useless. A better alternative that could support P2P and the bandwidth demand would be I2P.

Comment: @Jobiwan But if you configure the P2P client to use Tor as a SOCKS proxy, doesn't that broadcast information go through Tor? (Is this the Distributed Hash Table?)

Comment: @Jon My thinking - and possibly incorrect assumption - was that you could set Tor to be a SOCKS proxy for the trackers (as well as hash table). In my answer I did mention that a user would have to be careful that the client app didn't just ignore the proxy settings, and send data over the clearnet.

Comment: A Tor client can not accept incoming connections. A proxy is not a network interface. I'm not familiar with details on eMule, but if it broadcasts *"Hey everybody! Connect to me on a.b.c.d:p"* it doesn't matter that it goes through Tor; the identifying information is in the payload.